# Best way to map query result to DTO

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I want to make a complex query and map the result into a DTO. The DTO is below:

```
@Value(staticConstructor = "of")
public class TotalsDto {
    LocalDate date;
    long totals;
    long totalPerCategory;
    int categoryId;
    String categoryName;
}
```

My repository interface is extending from `JpaRepository`. This is throwing an `IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type`, because `TotalsDto` is not an Entity itself.

The repository is:

```
@Repository
public interface TotalsRepository extends JpaRepository<TotalsDto, Integer> { 

    @Query(value = "SELECT ...", nativeQuery = true)
    List<TotalsDto> getTotals(params...);
}
```

The query is getting data from other entities to build the DTO.
Any way to map every column to DTO? I tried to map it with the query below but it still getting `Not a managed class`.

```
SELECT my.package.TotalsDto.of(column1, subqueryResult1, subqueryResult2...)
```

Comment: You can refer this acticle: https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-projection-query-to-a-dto-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**1)** Make `TotalsDto` an interface

**2)** Create getters:

```
public interface TotalsDto{

    long getTotals();
    int getCategoryId();
    ...

}
```

Spring Data Jpa will then automatically create / fill you result object.

More on the subject [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections)

Comment: still getting `Not a managed type`. I also changed the repository parent to `org.springframework.data.repository.Repository` as mentioned in the link you sent, but getting the same error.

Comment: same here, either the docs are lacking or we're stupid - did you ever get it going @Leonardo ?

Comment: The interface-based projections I believe only support JPA interface queries.  The example provided in the documentation is:
 interface NamesOnly {

  String getFirstname();
  String getLastname();
}
interface PersonRepository extends Repository<Person, UUID> {

  Collection<NamesOnly> findByLastname(String lastname);
} You most likely need a SqlResultsSetMapping, and that's a twisted and poorly documented beast.

Answer (score 1):

The first type argument to `Repository` (or `JpaRepository`) must be a managed entity. Therefore, `JpaRepository<TotalsDto, Integer>` is invalid, as `TotalsDto` is not a managed entity. Change `TotalsDto` to a projection interface like @MaciejKowalski has suggested, and then pass a JPA entity to `Repository` as the first type argument, say, `Repository<Order, Integer>`.